# Is it possible to clock in and out of multiple tasks in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, tasks, org-mode

I get errors if I try to clock into multiple tasks in org-mode. There don't seem to be any references to this use case in the documentation.

- Can I multi-task?
- What breaks if I do?
- Bonus: is it feasible to define a function that enforces a maximum total effort value for all clocked in tasks?

Comment: This is too old to migrate, but you might have more luck asking on [the Emacs StackExchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/).